# handling memory for IDL sequence return types

Tags: c++, corba

I have an idl definition as follow

```
typedef sequence<octet> ByteArray;

interface Connection {
    ByteArray get_id ();
}
```

And there is this client side code

```
ByteArray * idToEncrypt = connection->get_id();
encryptId(idToEncrypt); 
... // rest of code
```

The function encryptId() has the signature `ByteArray* encryptId(ByteArray* idToEncrypt)`.  I cannot change this signature.

For automatic memory handling, the type of idToEncrypt was changed to ByteArray_var. The problem is I dont know how to get 'ByteArray *' from ByteArray_var and pass it to encryptId().

Is there a way to automatically handle memory allocated "idToEncrypt" and still pass it to encryptId() as "ByteArray *"?

Comment: What about `encryptId(&idToEncrypt.inout())` ?

Comment: Also check the new IDL to C++11 language mapping for CORBA, there sequence<octet> maps to a std::vector<int8_t> which is returned by value using C++11 move semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the `_var` [C++ mapping](http://www.omg.org/spec/CPP/) in the CORBA specs.

For a sequence type var, I think the best approach might be to use the `inout()` member, i.e.:

```
ByteArray_var idToEncrypt = connection->get_id();
encryptId(&idToEncrypt.inout());
```

`inout` returns a non-const reference and you're just taking the address of the underlying object with `&`.

*Do note*: `inout` does dereference the internal pointer, so it would be illegal to call `inout()` on a `_var` that doesn't hold a pointer. However, the call to get_id() *must* always return a valid pointer, so the code is OK without checking.

If you need a generic approach where you don't know if the `_var`is initialized, you could use:

```
ByteArray* p = idToEncrypt.operator->();
```

as `operator->` seems to be the only way to directly get at the pointer.